# retrieving assests based on meta data tag in ektron

Tags: ektron

I have added one MetaData definition in Ektron workarea and have added assets and contents based on the metadata that I have defined.Now I want to retrieve all the contents with that metaData tag.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend  either using a MetadataCriteria object or the Search API if you have it available.

To use the Metadata Criteria, follow the example at http://reference.ektron.com/developer/framework/content/contentmanager/getlistByMetadata.aspx

in short:

```
string metaDataToFilterBy = "Some Value";
long metaDataId = 115;//whatever the id of your metadata is in workarea>settings>configuration>metadata
ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager();
ContentMetadataCriteria criteria = new ContentMetadataCriteria();

criteria.AddFilter(metaDataId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, metaDataToFilterBy);

List<ContentData> contentList = contentManager.GetList(criteria);
```